# Mistake with growth factor but where?

Tags: economics, compound-interest

I did not get the same number as in the following statement:

> Since 1984, the Stockholm Stock Exchange (OMXS30) has risen by over
> 3,000 percent. This means that the stock market has risen by an
> average of 7 percent per year.

I get instead (1.07)^(2023-1984)=14, that would mean 14 times the money in return, so the rise would be 13 units i.e. 1300%. If I invested 1 unit in 1984 at 7 % compounded interest rate, at the end of year 2022 it would be worth 1.07 × 1.07 × 1.07 × 1.07 × ... = 14. It does not look like +3000% so there is some mistake somewhere but where?

Comment: Source? The date of the statement is crucial.

Comment: It's dated 10 jul 23 but that doesn't give any more info about how the statement is ever true anytime. I suppose it can be a self-contained question asking, in general, how many periods 7% need to accumulate to 3000%? I translated the original statement in Google Translate from a blog, but... there's nothing more there that adds more information. I mean, what I was asking for was if my understanding and calculation had a major mistake, and the common understanding would be something else e.g. monthly compounded or ...

Comment: O.K. In general your apprach seems right. Neverthelesss a link to the blog could clarify some things.

Comment: https://blogg.avanza.se/sa-investerar-andra-i-aktier-2023-se-popularaste-bolagen/ In the second paragraph but it's in Swedish. Could it be that the 7% is adjusted for 2% yearly inflation? But that seems wrong to do for a comparison.

Comment: If he wanted to say $\color{red}1300\%$ then the 7% would have made sense. It seems that there is a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you, but such statements often have poor arithmetic.  $\sqrt [39]{30} \approx 1.09$, so the return is about $9\%$ per year.  Certainly I would not count on "risen by $3000\%$" to mean $1$ turns into $31$ instead of $30$ and it won't change the result much anyway.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to assume that the 7% is adjusted with +2% for inflation? Then 9% would be 7%+2% on average, but I'm not sure why the measure would be inflation-adjusted here since inflation is usually not accounted for in these calculations. It'd be priced in when comparing investment alternatives which would be the purpose here.

Comment: No, I would assume they were just sloppy but of course I don't really know.